# Can we resize rows manually in datagrid?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Hi.. Just like we can resize columns in datagrid at run-time, similarily can this resizing functionality be applied to rows in datagrid in silverlight i.e. if the user can expand or collapse a row[image] according to his wish.

I have attached an image. Here just like the resizing cursor appears on columns, can such thing be done for rows so that they can be re-sized manually?

Answer (score 0):

You mean to change the height of the row?
I don't know how to do that, only by heavily changing the datagrid toolkit code

or you want to display additional info in the selected row?
This can be achieved by using detail view in the row:

sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate

URL of example: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/DataGrid-and-row-details-in-Silverlight-2.aspx

Comment: have tried using this but it simply adds new content below a selected row... My concern is to expand a selected row.

Comment: Ok, then try this: http://tech.pro/tutorial/949/silverlight-datagrid-tutorial-using-a-datagridtemplatecolumn